# Many-to-many User and Company association with multiple user 'groups'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this. My goal is to create a relationship like this:

- **Companies** can have many **Users** (team members/employees)
- **Users** can be part of many **Companies**
- **Companies** can have different groups of **Users** (i.e **Employee, Owner, Advisor, and Executive**)
- **Users** can be part of many groups (i.e. **User A** can be an **Employee** to **Company 1** and an **Advisor** to **Company 2**)

Basically, I want the ability to show a Company's profile and show all their Employees, Owners, Advisors, and Executives. Similarly, I am trying to also be able to search for users by whether they are an Employee, Owner, Advisor, or Executive. Additionally, a User may be associated with many different companies and many different groups.

My approach/belief right now is something along the lines of having these sorts of Rails relationships:

- **Companies** has_many_belongs_to_many **Users**
- **Users** has_many_belongs_to_many **Companies**
- **Companies** has_one **EmployeeTeam**, through: **Users**
- **Companies** has_one **OwnerTeam**, through: **Users**
- **Companies** has_one **AdvisorTeam**, through: **Users**
- **Companies** has_one **ExecutiveTeam**, through: **Users**
- **EmployeeTeam** has_many **Users**
- **OwnerTeam** has_many **Users**
- **AdvisorTeam** has_many **Users**
- **ExecutiveTeam** has_many **Users**

Honestly, I'm not sure if I am over complicating this, if this is an efficient way of doing this, or even if this way works. I'm fairly new to Rails and would appreciate any guidance/best practices. Thanks!

Comment: Can a user be in 2 different groups under the same company? and can a user be in a company but not in a group?

Comment: Yes and Yes. A user can be in 2 different groups under the same company. Also, a user could technically be in a company but not a group.

Comment: and are the group types the same across the different companies? or does each company have its own group types?

Comment: The group types will stay the same across all the companies (Employee, Advisor, Owner, Executive). Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Companies has_and_belongs_to_many Users
- Users has_and_belongs_to_many Companies
- User  has_and_belongs_to_many Groups
- Group belongs_to Company
- Group has_and_belongs_to_many Users
- EmployeeTeam is a subclass of Group
- OwnerTeam is a subclass of Group
- AdvisorTeam is a subclass of Group
- ExecutiveTeam is a subclass of Group
- Companies has_one EmployeeTeam
- Companies has_one OwnerTeam
- Companies has_one AdvisorTeam
- Companies has_one ExecutiveTeam
- Companies has_many Employees through EmployeeTeam, class User
- Companies has_many Owners through OwnerTeam, class User
- Companies has_many Advisors through AdvisorTeam, class User
- Companies has_many Executives through ExecutiveTeam, class User

This will give you the functions on Company:

```
company.users #all users
company.employees #all users with the group employee team
company.owners #all users with the group owner team
company.advisors #all users with the group advisor team
company.executives #all users with the group executive team
```

You will need to have the creation of Company create his groups

You will need to validate that a User doesn't associate with a group that it isn't associated with its company.

It will also allow you to write code for groups as a whole, and specific code for each group type

This will also only have 5 Database Tables

- companies
- groups
- users
- companies_users
- groups_users

Comment: Thank you! Quick question - when you say subclass would that be the same as using ActiveRecord's Single Table Inheritance?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the different groups didn't have unique data structures, but would have unique capabilities.  A Single Table Inheritance would fit that to a T.

Answer (score 0):

In a classical data design approach, I would consider to reference the group information in a junction table together with users and companies. Take a look at

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

In chapter 2.6 you see a classic many-to-many junction model with  "assemblies_parts" as junction table. There you could add a third relation. So, you'd get a "users_companies_groups" junction table. There you can freely assign relations between the three domains.

A problem might arise with restrictions: You don't want a user to be in two different groups at the same company. This can be solved, e.g., by taking only "user_id" and "company_id" as primary key. By that, a user is restricted to be in each company only once.

[Edit: corrected last statement on restrictions]

Comment: This would be a good solution as well.  Can you expound on how you would make requests for `users` given a `company` and desired `group`.

Comment: You can simply select over the junction table. The last time I did rails is a year ago, so I don't wanna give you wrong syntax, but it's basically a select clause with "where company id=wanted-c-id and group_id=wanted-g-id".

Comment: This approach, just to point it out, has a minor flaw: It basically says every group can exist in any company (that's how you asked for it). If there are only distinct groups available in some companies, you can either check validity in rails or do it by a more complex db model with two junction tables. The latter is "cleaner" (as the db checks data integrity), but has a higher performance impact (more tables means more joins when fetching the data).

Comment: You would also need to ensure uniqueness on the query level since the User can be in multiple groups within the same company, so any request for all Users on a company would have to append the `.uniq` clause.

Comment: Correction, you can ensure this by adding the `uniq: true` in the `has_many through` clause

Comment: I'm not sure if this isn't the same as setting the primary key as I've written, since the PK is also unique.

Comment: The issue is that since a user can associate with a company, via multiple groups.  The joins table would have duplicate company/user pairs (which is what the primary key uniqueness would eliminate).  but adding `uniq: true` to the `has_many through` clause ensures that requests for `users` on a `company` will never contain duplicate `users` even if they are double associated.